# Android eclipse ADT 'find references' bug

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt, android-library

my setup:

- Eclipse 3.6.2, ADT 15.0
- android library project B
- dependent android project A

With ADT 12 it was possible to use

```
-> right-click -> References -> Workspace
```

on a symbol of library B to find references of this symbol in the project A. This does not work anymore. Is there a workaround? Do you have the same issues? (Same applies to renaming, aso.)

Comment: Did you find the answer to your question ?

Comment: Checkout my answer below, might solve the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think checking your build path jars should solve the issue. If it doesn't try upgrading eclipse. I think that solved my problem.